# New StackExchange profile in testing

Tags: discussion

The new layout is [live on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112151/new-user-page-live-on-meta). Everyone is encouraged to post their feedback on the design. It will eventually move out to all the SE 2.0 sites (that's us!) I believe.

Update 11/23/2011: It's live on this site as well, so your profile is now the new design.

Comment: I was just coming to post this very question.

Comment: I rather like it after being able to play with it. The summary page seems like a lot of info at once but it doesn't feel like it...but that may be because I'm so familiar with it.

Comment: If you're missing the "alerts" for new responses and reputation, you might want to comment here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113333